# java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

Tags: java, netbeans, socket

recientemente me salió este error el cual he visto a que se puede deber (Ya el puerto esta siendo usado) lo raro y el problema que se me presenta es que cuando reviso los puertos en uso, el puerto seleccionado no esta siendo usado cosa que se me hace muy extraño, entonces decidi cambiar el puerto me seguia saliendo el mismo error, nose a que se deba o porque se esta usando 2 veces el puerto. Lo peor es que antes este problema no se me presentaba y realmente nose en que momento o que se hice para que me apareciera el error

> may 21, 2022 3:12:21 PM prueba_red_local.Servidor$5 run
> GRAVE: null
> java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
> at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
> at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)
> at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
> at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
> at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
> at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:237)
> at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:128)
> at prueba_red_local.Servidor$5.run(Servidor.java:449)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Este es el error

```js
public Servidor() {

        puertosAsignados();

        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        tabla.start();

        escucha.start();
        maquina_1.setVisible(false);
        maquina_2.setVisible(false);
        maquina_3.setVisible(false);
        maquina_4.setVisible(false);
        maquina_5.setVisible(false);
        maquina_6.setVisible(false);
    }
    Thread escucha = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                ServerSocket servidor = new ServerSocket(puertoRec); //Objeto para abrir un puerto y tenerlo a la escucha

                ArrayList<String> PermisosIp = new ArrayList<>(); //Creacion del array list
                int[] pivote;
                int bandera = 0;

                PreparedStatement ps;
                ResultSet rs;

                Connection xion = Conexion.getConexion(); //llamar a la clase conexion para conectar con base de datos
                ps = xion.prepareStatement("SELECT Ip, id_maquina FROM ListaDeIp"); //comando query que selecciona datos de tablas
                rs = ps.executeQuery();//Ejecuta comando

                while (rs.next()) { //ciclo para asignar variables de la base de dato al programa
                    bandera = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("id_maquina"));
                    PermisosIp.add(rs.getString("Ip"));
                }

                pivote = new int[bandera];

                switch (pivote.length) { //contador de cuantas maquinas mostrar (maximo 6)
                    case 0:
                        break;
                    case 1:
        //--------------------1 maquina registrada---------------------------//
                        maquina_1.setVisible(true);
                        jIp1.setText(datosMaquina(1));
                        break;
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------//
                    case 2:
        //------------------2 maquinas registradas---------------------------//
                        maquina_1.setVisible(true);
                        jIp1.setText(datosMaquina(1));
                        
                        maquina_2.setVisible(true);
                        jIp2.setText(datosMaquina(2));
                        break;
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------//
                    case 3:
        //------------------3 maquinas registradas---------------------------//
                        maquina_1.setVisible(true);
                        jIp1.setText(datosMaquina(1));
                        
                        maquina_2.setVisible(true);
                        jIp2.setText(datosMaquina(2));
                        
                        maquina_3.setVisible(true);
                        jIp3.setText(datosMaquina(3));
                        break;
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------//
                    case 4:
        //------------------4 maquinas registradas---------------------------//
                        maquina_1.setVisible(true);
                        jIp1.setText(datosMaquina(1));
                        
                        maquina_2.setVisible(true);
                        jIp2.setText(datosMaquina(2));
                        
                        maquina_3.setVisible(true);
                        jIp3.setText(datosMaquina(3));
                        
                        maquina_4.setVisible(true);
                        jIp4.setText(datosMaquina(4));
                        break;
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------//
                    case 5:
        //------------------5 maquinas registradas---------------------------//
                        maquina_1.setVisible(true);
                        jIp1.setText(datosMaquina(1));
                        
                        maquina_2.setVisible(true);
                        jIp2.setText(datosMaquina(2));
                        
                        maquina_3.setVisible(true);
                        jIp3.setText(datosMaquina(3));
                        
                        maquina_4.setVisible(true);
                        jIp4.setText(datosMaquina(4));
                        
                        maquina_5.setVisible(true);
                        jIp5.setText(datosMaquina(5));
                        break;
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------//
                    case 6:
        //------------------6 maquinas registradas---------------------------//
                        maquina_1.setVisible(true);
                        jIp1.setText(datosMaquina(1));
                        
                        maquina_2.setVisible(true);
                        jIp2.setText(datosMaquina(2));
                        
                        maquina_3.setVisible(true);
                        jIp3.setText(datosMaquina(3));
                        
                        maquina_4.setVisible(true);
                        jIp4.setText(datosMaquina(4));
                        
                        maquina_5.setVisible(true);
                        jIp5.setText(datosMaquina(5));
                        
                        maquina_6.setVisible(true);
                        jIp6.setText(datosMaquina(6));
                        break;
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------//
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                
                Socket prueba = servidor.accept();
                
                InetAddress Seguridad = prueba.getInetAddress(); //Variable que obtiene la ip cuando el cliente se conecta

                String IpFiltro = Seguridad.getHostAddress(); //Conversion de dicha variable a "String"

                for (String x : PermisosIp) {

                    if (!IpFiltro.equals(x)) {
                        
                        jTextArea1.append("Intruso detectado: " + IpFiltro);

                    } else {
                        String nick, ip, mensaje;

                        ArrayList<String> listaIP = new ArrayList<>();

                        PaqueteInstrucción paquete_recibido;

                        while (true) { //Ciclo para abrir infinitamente la conexión
                            Socket misocket = servidor.accept();//Metodo para aceptar todo lo que venga por el puerto seleccionado

                            ObjectInputStream paquetes_datos = new ObjectInputStream(misocket.getInputStream()); //Objeto que lee los datos de la clase "Cliente"

                            paquete_recibido = (PaqueteInstrucción) paquetes_datos.readObject(); //Igualación de "paquete_recibido" a "paquetes_datos"

                            nick = paquete_recibido.getNick(); //Guardando en la variable local "nick" el nick introducido en la clase "cliente"

                            ip = paquete_recibido.getIp(); //Guardando en la variable local "ip" el ip introducido en la clase "cliente"

                            mensaje = paquete_recibido.getMensaje(); //Guardando en la variable local "mensaje" el mensaje introducido en la clase "cliente"

                            if (!mensaje.equals(" online") && !mensaje.equals(" offline")) {

                                jTextArea1.append(nick + ": " + mensaje + " para: " + ip + "\n"); //Agregando la instruccion recibida al "TextArea"

                                Socket destinatario = new Socket(ip, puertoEnv); //puente para enviar un mensaje a otro destinatario

                                ObjectOutputStream reenvio = new ObjectOutputStream(destinatario.getOutputStream()); //Objeto para enviar el mensaje recibido

                                reenvio.writeObject(paquete_recibido); //Escribir el mensaje para el destinario asignado del cliente

                                reenvio.close();

                                destinatario.close(); //cierre del socket "destinatario"

                                misocket.close();//Cierra la conexion

                            } else if (mensaje.equals(" online")) {

                                //---------------------Deteccion del cliente------------------//
                                InetAddress localizacion = misocket.getInetAddress(); //Variable que obtiene la ip cuando el cliente se conecta

                                String IpRemota = localizacion.getHostAddress(); //Conversion de dicha variable a "String"

                                System.out.println("Online " + IpRemota); //Impresion en consola de que el cliente esta conectado + IP

                                listaIP.add(IpRemota); //Agregando las ip al array local

                                paquete_recibido.setIps(listaIP); //Pasar la lista al array para el cliente

                                for (String z : listaIP) {

                                    System.out.println("Array: " + z);

                                    Socket destinatario = new Socket(z, puertoEnv); //puente para enviar un mensaje a otro destinatario

                                    ObjectOutputStream reenvio = new ObjectOutputStream(destinatario.getOutputStream()); //Objeto para enviar el mensaje recibido

                                    reenvio.writeObject(paquete_recibido); //Escribir el mensaje para el destinario asignado del cliente

                                    jTextArea1.append(z + "Se ha conectado\n");

                                    if (jIp1.getText().equals(z)) {
                                        setNetcat1(true); //Enviar un true de conectado
                                    } else if(jIp2.getText().equals(z)){
                                        setNetcat2(true);
                                    } else if(jIp3.getText().equals(z)){
                                        setNetcat3(true);
                                    } else if(jIp4.getText().equals(z)){
                                        setNetcat4(true);
                                    } else if(jIp5.getText().equals(z)){
                                        setNetcat5(true);
                                    } else if(jIp6.getText().equals(z)){
                                        setNetcat6(true);
                                    } else {
                                        
                                    }

                                    reenvio.close();

                                    destinatario.close(); //cierre del socket "destinatario"

                                    misocket.close();//Cierra la conexion

                                }
                                //------------------------------------------------------------//
                            } else if (mensaje.equals(" offline")) {

                                InetAddress localizacion = misocket.getInetAddress(); //Variable que obtiene la ip cuando el cliente se conecta

                                String IpRemota = localizacion.getHostAddress(); //Conversion de dicha variable a "String"

                                System.out.println("offline " + IpRemota); //Impresion en consola de que el cliente esta conectado + IP

                                listaIP.add(IpRemota); //Agregando las ip al array local

                                paquete_recibido.setIps(listaIP); //Pasar la lista al array para el cliente

                                for (String z : listaIP) {

                                    System.out.println("Array: " + z);

                                    Socket destinatario = new Socket(z, puertoEnv); //puente para enviar un mensaje a otro destinatario

                                    ObjectOutputStream reenvio = new ObjectOutputStream(destinatario.getOutputStream()); //Objeto para enviar el mensaje recibido

                                    reenvio.writeObject(paquete_recibido); //Escribir el mensaje para el destinario asignado del cliente

                                    jTextArea1.append(z + "Se ha desconectado\n");

                                    if (jIp1.getText().equals(z)) {
                                        setNetcat1(false); //Enviar un true de conectado
                                    } else if(jIp2.getText().equals(z)){
                                        setNetcat2(false);
                                    } else if(jIp3.getText().equals(z)){
                                        setNetcat3(false);
                                    } else if(jIp4.getText().equals(z)){
                                        setNetcat4(false);
                                    } else if(jIp5.getText().equals(z)){
                                        setNetcat5(false);
                                    } else if(jIp6.getText().equals(z)){
                                        setNetcat6(false);
                                    } else {
                                        
                                    }

                                    reenvio.close();

                                    destinatario.close(); //cierre del socket "destinatario"

                                    misocket.close();//Cierra la conexion

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());
            }

        }
    });

    Thread tabla = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Servidor ob = new Servidor();
            ob.prueba(Encendido_1, Netcat1);
            ob.prueba(Encendido_2, Netcat2);
            ob.prueba(Encendido_3, Netcat3);
            ob.prueba(Encendido_4, Netcat4);
            ob.prueba(Encendido_5, Netcat5);
            ob.prueba(Encendido_6, Netcat6);
            
        }
    });
    
    public void prueba(JPanel a, boolean b){
        while (true) {
                if (b == false) {
                    a.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                } else if (b == true) {
                    a.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                }
            }
    }

    public void puertosAsignados() {

        try {

            ResultSet rs;

            Connection xion = Conexion.getConexion();
            PreparedStatement ps = xion.prepareStatement("SELECT PuertoServ, PuertoClient FROM Puertos WHERE ID=2"); //Comando Sql
            rs = ps.executeQuery(); //Ejecutando comando SQL

            if (rs.next()) { //Condicional que verifica si existe un dato 
                puertoRec = rs.getInt("PuertoServ");
                puertoEnv = rs.getInt("PuertoClient");
                
            } else { //En caso de que no exista dato

                puertoEnvio = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Puerto por el que enviara los paquetes: ");

                puertoRecibo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Puerto para recibir los paquetes: ");

                puertoEnv = Integer.parseInt(puertoEnvio);
                puertoRec = Integer.parseInt(puertoRecibo);
                
                ps = xion.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Puertos (PuertoServ, PuertoClient) VALUES (?,?)"); //Comando para agregar datos a base de dato
                ps.setInt(1, puertoRec);
                ps.setInt(2, puertoEnv);
                ps.executeUpdate();
                
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
        }
    }
    
    public String datosMaquina(int a){
        String bandera = "";
        try{
            
            ResultSet rs;

            Connection xion = Conexion.getConexion();
            PreparedStatement ps = xion.prepareStatement("SELECT Ip FROM ListaDeIp WHERE id_maquina= "+ a +""); //Comando Sql
            rs = ps.executeQuery(); //Ejecutando comando SQL
            
            if(rs.next()){
            
            bandera = rs.getString("Ip");
            
            } else {
                
            }
            
        } catch(SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
        }
        
        return bandera;
        
    }

}
```

Y este es el codigo del que me esta arrojando el error. Nose si esta creando 2 escuchas o algo del estilo pero ya he revisado y me parece que no lo hace. Por favor necesito ayuda

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en que en el segundo hilo el hilo "tabla" estaba creando un objeto de la propia clase haciendo que cargue todo otra vez, entonces lo arregle de la siguiente manera

```js
Thread tabla = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            
            while(true){
            prueba(Encendido_1, Netcat1);
            prueba(Encendido_2, Netcat2);
            prueba(Encendido_3, Netcat3);
            prueba(Encendido_4, Netcat4);
            prueba(Encendido_5, Netcat5);
            prueba(Encendido_6, Netcat6);
            }
        }
    });
```